# I have made an scala library but how can I release it to maven, sonatype or other

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, sonatype

How can I release a jar to an artifactory and which do you recommend, is there a guide or tutorial to use with sbt, thanks.

Comment: The command is `sbt publish`.  You need to provide credentials that allow you to publish to the repo.  The sbt website should have a guide.  Knowing the command name should make it easier to find, I hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an SBT plugin that simplifies the workflow for you - `sbt-sonatype`. Check [this](https://github.com/xerial/sbt-sonatype) github project and just follow the steps described there.

[This](https://github.com/izmailoff/Spray-mongo-record/tree/master/project) project is an example that uses the `sbt-sonatype` plugin.